# iPhone scrolling text

Tags: iphone, text, scroll

I'm currently making a role-playing game, and I want the text to scroll like all the other RPGs I've played.

How would I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a UITableView.  Add the latest message to the bottom cell, insure it is scrolled into view.  This also allows for users to review previous messages as desired. Tables and cells are fairly easy to customise to suit your desired look and feel.